# Marginalization question $\Pr[a] = E_X[\Pr[\ a|X\ ]\ ]$

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-expectation

I'm reading explanation of a theorem, and there's one step that I can't understand. I know it should be simple enough, but I just can't think of the reasoning atm.

The step says,

> According to Marginalization, $\Pr[a] = E_X[\Pr[\ a|X\ ]\ ]$

Why is this true? What is the meaning of Marginalization? Also, I know expected values of a random variable, but what does it mean to have an expected value of a probability $(\Pr[a|X])$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I would consider it is, instead of the random event $a$, to consider the indicator random variable $I_a$ which takes the value $1$ when $a$ occurs and $0$ when it does not.  For example $$E[I_a]=\Pr(a).$$

The [law of total expectation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation) gives $$E[I_a] = E_X[\,E[I_a|X ]\, ]$$ which corresponds to the result you state.

Comment: Ah, this makes sense. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$\mathsf P(a\mid X)$ is the name of a function mapping values of the random variable to a marginal probability measure.

$$\mathsf P(a\mid X)(x) = \mathsf P(a\mid X=x)$$

It's similar to the way we sometimes write a probability mass function as: $\mathsf P_X(x) = \mathsf P(X=x)$

For a discrete random variable the expression becomes:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(a) & = \mathsf E_X[\mathsf P(a\mid X)]
\\ &= \sum_{x\in\chi} \mathsf P(a\mid X=x)\mathsf P(X=x)
\\ & = \sum_{x\in\chi} \mathsf P(a, X=x)
\end{align}$$

This is just the Law of Total Probability in another guise.

And for a continuous random variable this is:

$$\begin{align}
\mathsf P(a) & = \mathsf E_X[\mathsf P(a\mid X)]
\\ &= \int_{\chi} \mathsf P(a\mid X=x)\,f_X(x)\operatorname d x
\end{align}$$